# Get right function inside of an object

Tags: javascript

in this code, on line 15 the 
"this" pointer refers to socket and not my Object Network. What should I do to actually get the Network object? Sorry for this "noob" question but I searched for a while on google and I didn't even know what to type to find an answer..

```
var Network = function(ip, port){
  this.host = "ws://"+ip+":"+port;
  this.socket = new WebSocket(this.host);
  this.socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
  var ByteBuffer = dcodeIO.ByteBuffer;

  this.socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log('Connected to the WebSocket server');
  };

  this.socket.onmessage = function(e){
    var bytearray = new Uint8Array(e.data);
    switch(bytearray[0])
    {
    case 2: this.handleLoginAnswer(bytearray); break; //line 15 
    default:
      alert("received a wrong packet")
    }
  };

  this.handleLoginAnswer = function(packet){
    var bytearray = new Uint8Array(e.data);
    var reader = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytearray);
    var opcode = reader.readUint8();

    if(opcode != 2)
      return;

    var result = reader.readUint8();
    switch(result){
      case 1: displayValidate("Sucessfully registered"); break;
      case 2: displayError("Username is already taken"); break;
      case 3: displayError("Email is already taken"); break;
    }

    function displayValidate(message){
      $("#register-messagebox").html("<div class=\"alert-message\" style=\"background-color:#27ae60;\">" + message + "</div>");
    }

    function displayError(error){
      $("#register-messagebox").html("<div class=\"alert-message\" style=\"background-color:#e74c3c;\">" + error + "</div>");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: save `this` to a local variable somewhere around line 1 and use this variable inside the callback.

Comment: Like every one comment, 
assign this to a variable .
http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/XD8Mx/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common issue. An option is to maintain reference to it, using the closure:

```
// Get a reference to the network
var network = this;

this.socket.onmessage = function(e){
  var bytearray = new Uint8Array(e.data);
  switch(bytearray[0]) {
    // Access the outside-defined 'network' here
    case 2: network.handleLoginAnswer(bytearray); break;
    default:
      alert("received a wrong packet");
  }
};
```

Another one is to use `Function.bind`, to force the handler to be executed with `network` being the `this`, instead of the `socket`:

```
this.socket.onmessage = function(e){
  var bytearray = new Uint8Array(e.data);
  switch(bytearray[0]) {
    // It's safe to use 'this' here
    case 2: this.handleLoginAnswer(bytearray); break;
    default:
      alert("received a wrong packet");
  }
// Bind the function, so that it is always executed in this context
}.bind(this);
```

In your case, yet another one is to not use `this` to refer to the `handleLoginAnswer` function, since it is defined on the same place anyway. If you change it's definition from this:

```
this.handleLoginAnswer = function() { /* ... */ };
```

to this:

```
var handleLoginAnswer = function() { /* ... */ };
```

And the call from:

```
this.handleLoginAnswer(bytearray);
```

To:

```
handleLoginAnswer(bytearray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put:

```
var self = this;  // or other name to suit
```

and refer to `self` when you want the object.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `Network` object, cache the reference to `this`:

```
var self = this;
```

And then you may access it using `self` instead of `this`

```
case 2: self.handleLoginAnswer(bytearray); break; //line 15
```

Because the way JavaScript closures work, you will have access to `self` from within

Answer (score 1):

Immediate invocation is your friend:

```
this.socket.onmessage = function(that) {
    return function(e) {
        // Your callback code here, where `that` is referencing your `Object Network`
    }
}(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

a common answer to this problem is this:

```
var myclass = function () {

    var self = this;

    self.host = 'my host';

    self.goHere = function () {
        //here use self to refer to myclass or this to refer to goHere function
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Save a reference of this, and then use the reference instead of `this`

```
var Network = function(ip, port){
   var _this = this;
   ...
      case 2: _this.handleLoginAnswer(bytearray); break; //line 15
```